# Nix -- how to use addAutoPatchelfSearchPath correctly?

Tags: nixos, nix, patchelf

I'm packaging a tool that includes some shared objects natively, and I think the right approach to add those objects to the rpath is to use the `addAutoPatchelfSearchPath` function to the `installPhase` of my Nix expression, but it's not picking up the `.so` libs as expected. I've tried setting the search path explicitly, relatively, etc. What would the correct usage be?

```
installPhase = ''
    mkdir -p $out
    addAutoPatchelfSearchPath $(pwd)
    cp -r $src $out
''
```

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe a bit old, but in case someone still needs it, you should certainly use a path that is inside the `$out` directory (if you source it from the source file, since this will be deleted after build in has no chance to end up in a derivation):

```
addAutoPatchelfSearchPath $out/opt/Breitbandmessung
```

Note that the `$out/lib` folder is included by default.